# What algorithm is Newton using in the "De analysi" to extract the square root of a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algorithms, radicals, math-history

I'm reading a 1745 English translation of Newton's *De analysi* (apparently the most up-to-date there is, surprisingly). The Latin is [here](http://www.newtonproject.ox.ac.uk/view/texts/normalized/NATP00204).

In this tract he shows how to use the integral power rule for rational exponents (together with a sum rule: the area under a sum of curves being the sum of the areas) to find quadratures, and he gives examples in three types of how to deal with the case of integrating $y$ when it is not a polynomial: examples using long division e.g. $y=a^2/(b+x)$, examples using the extraction of square roots e.g. $y=\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$, and examples using "the resolution of affected equations" when $y$ is defined implicitly via a polynomial $f(x,y)=0$.

For the second example, $y=\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$, he uses an algorithm to extract the root, but I don't recognize the algorithm. Here's an image:

[image]

Note that Newton is not applying his binomial series: he is doing something else.

I realize this is equivalent to the following procedure. Assume $y=\sum b_ix^i$ and we are given $y^2=\sum a_ix^i$; the goal is to solve for the $b_i$. Using the Cauchy product, squaring the first equation gives $y^2=\sum c_ix^i$ where $c_i=\sum_{k=0}^ib_kb_{i-k}$. Pattern matching the coefficients $c_i=a_i$ allows us to recursively solve for the $b_i$, because $c_i$ is the first term to use $b_i$. Thus

$$c_0=b_0^2$$
$$c_1=2b_0b_1$$
$$c_2=2b_0b_2+b_1^2$$
$$c_3=2b_0b_3+2b_1b_2$$
$$c_4=2b_0b_4+2b_1b_3+b_2^2$$
etc.

But Newton is clearly doing something else: drawing on some established algorithm with a visual representation. I don't think it's his algorithm. So:

**Three Questions**

- How does the algorithm work?
- Does the algorithm have a name?
- Who first used the algorithm?

**EDITED**

After puzzling it out a little, I at least see the answer to my first question. Here is the procedure applied to $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$.

Step 1: Guess $a$. Store this as the latest estimate $S_0$.

Step 2: Square, giving $a^2$, then subtract from the radicand: $x^2$. Store this as the latest remainder $R_0$.

Step 3: Update $S_i$ to $S_{i+1}$ by adding a term $y_i$ to $S_i$ so that $2y_iS_0$ agrees with the lowest-degree term of $R_i$. In this case, we want to add $y_0$ so that the lowest-degree term of $2y_0a$ agrees with $x^2$. Hence $y_0=x^2/2a$. The estimate $S_0$ is thus updated to $S_1=a+x^2/2a$.

Step 4: Multiply $y_i$ by $(2S_i+y_i)$, then subtract from the last remainder and store the result as the latest remainder $R_{i+1}$. In this case, we multiply $x^2/2a$ by $(2a+x^2/2a)$, giving $x^2+x^4/4a^2$. Subtracting from the last remainder gives $-x^4/4a^2$.

Step 5: Repeat steps 3/4.

Just to illustrate for the next term, we want to add $y$ to that $2ya=-x^4/4a^2$. Thus we add $y=-x^4/8a^3$ and the estimate is updated to $a+x^2/2a-x^4/8a^3$. Now we multiply

$$-\frac{x^4}{8a^3}\left(2\left(a+\frac{x^2}{2a}\right)-\frac{x^4}{8a^3}\right)=-\frac{x^4}{4a^2}-\frac{x^6}{8a^4}+\frac{x^8}{64a^6}$$

Subtracting from the previous remainder $-x^4/4a^2$ yields the new remainder

$$\frac{x^6}{8a^4}-\frac{x^8}{64a^6}$$

and so on.

Comment: I think he is using the analogue of the algorithm for
[computing square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) digit by digit,
except he is applying it to power series coefficient
by coefficient.

Comment: The continued fraction makes me think he's using Newton's method (iterative as @Somos points out) for solving $f(y) = y^2 - a^2 - x^2$ for $y$ using a specific starting value: $y_{i+1} = y_i - (y_i^2 - a^2 - x^2)/(2y_i)$.

Answer (score 8):

*Partial answer with historical context*

After googling "square root of a polynomial," I found that the algorithm is lucidly described in many standard 19th and early 20th century algebra textbooks for high schools and colleges: e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=R-RHAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA281&dq=%22square%20root%20of%20a%20polynomial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia1Pun4fHuAhUNm-AKHW_1B_QQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22square%20root%20of%20a%20polynomial%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ouMSAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA224&dq=%22square%20root%20of%20a%20polynomial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirn7ez3vHuAhUqZN8KHVKqD4QQ6AEwBHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22square%20root%20of%20a%20polynomial%22&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=5lxRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA135&dq=%22square%20root%20of%20a%20polynomial%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirn7ez3vHuAhUqZN8KHVKqD4QQ6AEwCHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22square%20root%20of%20a%20polynomial%22&f=false). (How poorly modern textbooks fare by comparison!)

Encouraged by this evidence, I decided to glance at George Chrystal's famous textbook *Algebra* (first published 1886). He gives a [thorough discussion](https://archive.org/details/algebraelementar01chryuoft/page/215/mode/2up) in section 17 ("Square root of an integral function of $x$") in Chapter XI ("Arithmetical theory of surds") in volume 1. He also leaves a historical footnote, dating the algorithm to 1557 in English. I reproduce this passage here for ease of reference:

> When an integral function of $x$ is a complete square as regards $x$,
> its square root can be found by a method analogous to that explained
> in $\S12$, for finding the square root of a number. Although the
> method is of little interest, either theoretically or practically, we
> give a brief sketch of it here, because it illustrates at once the
> analogy and the fundamental difference between arithmetical and
> algebraical operations.*
>
> I. We may restate Proposition I. of $\S 12$, understanding now $A$ and
> $B$ to mean integral functions of $x$.
>
> II. If
> $F=p_ox^{2n}+p_1x^{2n-1}+\cdots+p_{2n}$, and if
> $$\sqrt{F}=(q_nx^n+q_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+q_{n-p+1}x^{n-p+1})+(q_{n-p}x^{n-p}+\cdots+q_0)=P+Q$$ say; and if we suppose the first $p$ terms, namely
> $P=q_nx^n+q_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+q_{n-p+1}x^{n-p+1}$, of $\sqrt{F}$ to be
> known, then the next $p$ terms will be the first $p$ terms in the
> integral part of $(F-P^2)/2P$.
>
> For we have $$F=P^2+2PQ+Q^2$$ hence
> $$\frac{F-P^2}{2P}=Q+\frac{Q^2}{2P}$$ Now the degree of the integral
> part of $Q^2/2P$ is $2(n-p)-n=n-2p$. Hence $Q^2/2P$ will at most
> affect the term in $x^{n-2p}$. Hence $(F-P^2)/2P$ will be identical
> with $Q$ down to the term in $x^{n-2p+1}$ inclusive. In other words,
> the first $n-p-(n-2p)=p$ terms obtained by dividing $F-P^2$ by $2P$
> will be the $p$ terms of the square root which follow $P$.
>
> We may use this rule to obtain the whole of the terms one at a time,
> the highest being of course
> found by inspection as the square root of
> the highest term of the radicand; or we may obtain a certain number in
> this way, and then obtain the rest by division.$\dagger$
>
> $*$ The method was probably obtained by analogy from the arithmetical process. It was first given by Recorde in *[The Whetstone of Witte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Whetstone_of_Witte)*
> (black letter, 1557), the earliest English work on algebra.
>
> $\dagger$ Just as in division, we may, if we please, arrange the
> radicand according to ascending powers of $x$. The final result will
> be the same whichever arrangement be adopted, provided the radicand is
> a complete square. If this is not the case the operation may be
> prolonged indefinitely just as in continued division. We leave the
> learner to discover the meaning of the result obtained in such cases.
> The full discussion of the matter would require some reference to the
> theory of infinite series.

Comment: Chrystal is good stuff. Many years ago, I bought the big orange print version. I have since found it on line - a search easily finds a pdf. It is just images, so I ocr-ed it to make it searchable. A lot of interesting information there.