# Why is square root by long division found so?

Tags: math-history

We were taught the long division method of finding square root in junior classes. The  logic behind the method used to be unclear, it remains so even now! However, we learnt and practiced the algorithm well. To me it appears that the identity $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$ lies behind the method. However this seems to be only the minimal idea. So extensions and generalizations are welcome here. See the picture below as I can't type this stuff. Some one else may edit it properly.

[image]

Comment: That is some poor alignment here.  You should align the digits with the blocks of the pair of digits below for which you are performing that one stage.  Anyway, the obvious generalisation $(aB+b)^n=a^nB^n+(na^{n-1}B^{n-1}+\dots+b^{n-1})bs$ works for the $n$-th root in base $B$ (group the digits in blocks of $n$ left and right of the $B$-decimal point, start with the most significant block and work downwards, ...).

Comment: Could you actually *explain* what you are doing?

Comment: This is based on the formula you quote but you need to use in a different manner. If you have found some digits of the square root the method allows find the next digit. This is generalized by Horner to get real roots of polynomials digit by digit upto any desired level. The long division process follows the same steps applied to equation $x^2-a=0$.

Comment: Essentially you guess an approximate root and change the equation by subtracting root. Next change the equation for multiplying the root by 10. Again guess and repeat. This way you find the root digit by digit. The process is damn simple if the equation is of the form $x^2-a=0$.

Comment: @fleablood Reading this post many would do some lip service, even if their remarks go off the tangent,like the first (opening) comment posted above. You may see my little attempt below.

Comment: You might like to know this is how the master Newton himself extracted square roots, too! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029310/what-algorithm-is-newton-using-in-the-de-analysi-to-extract-the-square-root-of

Comment: Google "square root by hand method" to find lots of commentary.

Comment: For good visualization of the method you can watch the following video at youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7kesuMnqhs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is based on my comments to the question.

Consider that you have evaluate the square root of $a$. Let $x$ be the square root and $h$ be the least significant digit of the square root and $b$ be the number formed from $x$ by removing this least significant digit $h$. Then we have $x=10b+h$. (for example consider $a=144,x=12,b=1,h=2$).

The process of long division allows you to find $h$ given $a, b$. Thus we can find the next digit of square root if previous digits are known.

Our job is to find $h$ such that $(10b+h)^2=a$ or $$(2\cdot 10b+h)h=a-(10b)^2$$ the subtraction in right hand side is done by placing digits accordingly (for $a=144,b=1$ you place the digit $1$ of $b$ below $1$ of $a$ and get $44$ so that this is essentially doing $a-(10b)^2$).

Now analyze the left hand side. $2\cdot 10b$ involves doubling the number $b$ and multiplying further by $10$ to make space for next digit $h$. We have to choose next digit $h$ so that the new number $(20b+h)$ when multiplied by $h$ equals the number obtained after subtraction on right hand side. This is exactly what we do in the long division process (try to see for the example $a=144,b=1$ and you can easily guess that $21\cdot 1=21,22\cdot 2=44$).

---

Consider the same in terms of polynomials and roots. Let us solve $x^2-a=0$ digit by digit. We guess the root $b$ (which is the approximate square root of first two digits of $a$) and find an equation whose roots are $t=x-b$. This equation is clearly $$(t+b) ^2-a=0$$ Next multiply the roots by $10$ so that $z=10t$ gives $$(z+10b)^2-100a=0$$ or $$z(20b+z)=100a - 100b^2$$

Let us see that $100a$ is essentially about getting two more digits from $a$ and then subtracting $100b^2$ from it means that we subtract $b^2$ from first two digits of $a$ and bring in next two digits from $a$. The guess for $z$ is based on $z(20b+z)$ which is doubling $b$, creating next digit $z$ and multiplying it by $z$.

We can continue the process by subtracting $z$ and multiplying by $10$ and get another equation. The pattern remains same and can be continued till any desired number of digits.

---

The mysterious part in the long division process is doubling the divisor at each step and creating space for quotient as next digit. I have tried to explain that part in both the approaches above.

Answer (score 6):

For $3$ or $4$ digit numbers you were using $$(10a+b)^2=100a^2+(20a+b)b$$

For $5$ or $6$ digit numbers you would have used the messier $$(100a+10b+c)^2=10000a^2+(2000a+ 100b)b+(200a+ 20 b+c)c$$

So you would separate the number to be square-rooted into $100$s, in your example $27,04$

and it looked like

```
       ?  ?
     ------ 
     |27,04
```

The largest square less than or equal to $27$ is $25=5^2$ so you write

```
       5  ?
     ------ 
   5 |27,04
     |25
     ---
     | 2,04
```

You then double the $5$ you have written at the top to give $10$ and then add an extra digit $X$ so $10X \times X$ is a large as possible but does not exceed $204$: $102 \times 2= 204$ works exactly

```
       5  2
     ------ 
   5 |27,04
     |25
     ---
 102 | 2,04
     | 2,04
     ------
          0
```

So $\sqrt{2704} =52$

If the result had not been exact, you could have continued the same way, bringing down two more digits (possibly $00$).

My school thought this a waste of time and instead taught us to use logarithm tables.

Comment: Interestingly I (a 30-something American with a pure math degree) had never seen this algorithm until recently, when I discovered it in... Newton! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029310/what-algorithm-is-newton-using-in-the-de-analysi-to-extract-the-square-root-of

Comment: @symplectomorphic I am a 70-something American. This method was taught in the schools when I was young; but discontinued one year before I would have learned it.

Comment: I learned this method in 4th grade, but I think the reason was that my school's math specialist had an ancient hand calculator and a student (me) willing to execute an algorithm with it, and he thought this would be a suitable algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Let us do it with a trinomial
$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac$$ see the fig.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I’ll just add the following intuition to the other answers.

Suppose you are extracting the square root of $x$. First you guess, say, $x_0$. If $x_0^2\neq x$, then you must correct your guess by adding some new term $x_1$ to your initial guess $x_0$. Your guess for $\sqrt{x}$ is thus updated to $x_0+x_1$, whose square is $x_0^2+\color{red}{2x_0x_1+x_1^2}$.

The key point of the algorithm is that incrementing your *guess* by $x_1$ increments the *square of your guess* by the amount in red, which can be written $\color{red}{x_1(2x_0+x_1)}$. This fact helps you determine by how much to increment your guess.

Now apply this idea to $\sqrt{2704}$. First we guess $50$, since $50^2=2500$ gets us pretty close. The gap between the squares is $204$. If we increment our guess of $50$ by some amount $a$, we’ll increment the square of our guess by $a(2\cdot50+a)$. We’d like this to be as close to $204$ as possible. Notice $a=1$ increments by $101$, but $a=2$ increments by $204$: perfect! So we increment our initial guess of $50$ by $2$, and since that fills the gap perfectly we’re done! We’ve discovered $2704$ is a perfect square, and we iteratively arrived at $52$ as the square root.

It all boils down to noting how the square of your estimate changes when you change your estimate.

Answer (score 2):

Good explanation from geimetey. My original submission has been done by my friend Zaffar. That's because I am not familiar with formalities if stack exchange.
Few points I clarify in this context:
(1) The division method can be extended for any n-root. Sat for cube root :
Start with a number bB+s where B is the base; a and b are integers. (bB +a) ^3 =(bB)^3 + 3a(bB)^2 + 3(bB)a^2 + a^3.
Let us group three at a time from right. So, two groups. Left group has only (bB)^3 and right group has 3a(bB)^2 + 3(bB)a^2 + a^3. One has to find suitable b such that right group matches. Fir actual numbers, one has to search largest close number for a and b at every step.
Generalising the geometry approach, this can thenbe compared with funding suitable 3D visualisation where in stead of area, it willill be  volume.
(2) For any n-root, the method is similar. For visualisation, one can conceive n dimensional hypercubes.